# Fllink Web UI not displaying records received in a Custom Source implementation

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have build a custom source to process a log stream in Flink.
The program is running fine and giving me the desired results after processing the records.

But, when I check the Web UI, I do not see the counts. Below is the screenshot:
[Records/Bytes Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsokp.png)

Answer (score 12):

Flink chained all the operators of your pipeline into one operator: `Source -> FlatMap -> ProcessLog -> Sink`. Thus, this single operator contains the source and the sink. Additionally, Flink can neither measure the amount of bytes read by a source nor the number of bytes written by a sink. It can only measure the bytes sent between operators. Since the source and sink are executed in the same operator, the web UI does not show you any bytes sent/received.

Comment: Using rebalance between the source and the sink, the job is splitted into two operators, as solution if you want to see the metrics, but it makes no sense (programmaticly speaking). You can add other metrics in task metrics, useful for this case.